# How to inject SharedPreferences to Background service using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, service, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject SharedPrefernces to `Timer` foreground service class. I use `@EntryPoint` annotation over service class.

`ApplicationModule class`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class ApplicationModule() {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): SharedPreferences {
      return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)
  }
}
```

`Timer service class`

```
@EntryPoint
class Timer : Service() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences
    ...
    }
```

When I run this code, I get this error:
 `@EntryPoint com.beu.coroutineskotlin.Timer must also be annotated with @InstallIn [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.warning: File for type 'com.beu.coroutineskotlin.App_HiltComponents' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried on a service. however, i think you must use `@AndroidEntryPoint` and not `@EntryPoint`. `@EntryPoint` is used to create a custom entry point like this https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points.html